# angular 7 image display in a angular material table

Tags: angular, image, display

I am retriving data from mongodb and trying it to display it in a angular material table, in which one of the data is a image path. i dono how to bind it in a angular material table

I tried to bind image path to angular material table..
    this is what am getting in console
    `WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value background-image:url(C:\fakepath\short photo.jpeg) (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).`

```xml
<ng-container matColumnDef="image">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Thumbnail Image</th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let book" style="background-image:url({{book.image}})"></td>
</ng-container>
```

i want to bind the image path to the table td and display it in the table

Comment: I think you have to use two way resolve your problem first `this.image = this.sanitization.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${element.image})`);` and second is `[ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+imageUrl+')'}"` for more information read this https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: Can you provide sample URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help you to get solution.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="images">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Images </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':'url('+ element.images +')','background-size':'cover'}"></td>
</ng-container>
```

Also check on stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6prp2u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

If you are think to use `DomSanitizer`:

constructor :

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

URL:

```
this.trustedDashboardUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("URL");
```